# Changing the colour of 1 cell based on other cells (conditionally formatted) colour in that row

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I am creating a spreadsheet, I have columns in my table that perform validation checks (columns C to Y) from data from other sheets (uses conditional formatting) with the cells turning green if valid and red if invalid.

I would like column B to be red if any of cells in the same row but in column C to Y are shaded red.

and if they are all green I would like the cell in column B to be green

is it possible to do this with conditional or will I need to create a macro, if so does anyone have any pointers  on how this would be approached?

hopefully what I described makes sense, will happily elaborate

any help appreciated

Comment: So, instead of trying to look at the color of a cell, why don't you ask yourself what is making that cell that color, then use that information to format your other cells?

Comment: you have to re-think what you said, because it translates directly to code.   .... what you really want `if they are all green, the cell in column B would be green, otherwise the cell in column B would be red` .... this is different from what you wrote because any missing green cell will produce a red in column B .... your description has an _unknown_ state that happens when one of the cells is neither red nor green

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function-based CF rule to apply the coloring.  Eg: this would return True if there are any cells in `rng` with a red fill as the result of a CF rule (using the `DisplayFormat` property of each cell)

```
Function AnyRed(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, rv As Boolean
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 255 Then
            rv = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    AnyRed = rv
End Function
```

In your "master" cell apply a default green fill, then apply a CF rule using the formula and have that apply a red fill when the formula returns True.